# Recursively find keypair relationships in python list/df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, recursion

I am trying to resolve pairs of ints from a list of 5 million in python.

They represent pairs of relationships for a network of records.

I believe recursion will be the way to do this but I can't find good examples or the right terminology to describe the problem.

I want to

- loop through every record on either side of the relationship
- loop through all other relatives to every record on either side
- combine all found records under a single group (list,dict,whatever is easiest) so I can assign them record IDs

```
import pandas as pd

df_list = [[5213728 ,7381649],
           [2538095 ,5213728],
           [5213728 ,8163900],
           [3453455 ,3434644]
           ]
df_cols = ['MATCHED_KEY','SKEY']

#build a list of unique records
masterlist = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df['SKEY'].drop_duplicates()),pd.DataFrame(df['MATCHED_KEY'].drop_duplicates().rename('SKEY'))])


for idx,row in masterlist.iterrows():
    k = row['SKEY']

    #I imagine the next step is to go back through the df and keep adding more keys from both sides to a list until I've exhausted all links, then remove them from my master list and continue...
```

An ideal output would be something like:

```
{ 1: [2538095, 5213728,7381649, 8163900],
  2: [3453455, 3434644 ]
}
```

But anything that finds all related records and groups them should suffice

Answer (score 0):

In your case do `networkx`

```
import networkx as nx 
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'MATCHED_KEY', 'SKEY')
l = list(nx.connected_components(G))
d = dict(zip(range(len(l)), l))
d
{0: {5213728, 7381649, 8163900, 2538095}, 1: {3434644, 3453455}}
```